# Adding the abstract to the front page in Latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Included below is my LaTeX code. By default the abstract is on the first page following the title page. But the title page has lots of space below, and my abstract will be short, so is there anyway to include it below the title page components?

code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno,a4paper,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{amssybm}%for math bold

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}%for the margins headers footers etc

\usepackage{hyperref}%for the hyperlinks-COOL and must use

\usepackage[tt]{titlepic}%package i downloaded to put a pic in the titlepage

\usepackage{helvet}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}%options to use names like redviolet and others

\begin{document}

\title{title}

\titlepic{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\setlength\fboxrule{4pt}
 \fcolorbox{Plum}{green}{\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{pic}}}

\author{\Huge my name}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}

abstract text here

\end{abstract}

document text here

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your title page to `minipage`

```
\begin{minipage}[h]{\textwidth}
    \maketitle
\end{minipage}
```

Then you can add text below it.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The abstract is still on another page.